# Two controllers: API and View?

Tags: api, laravel, view, controller

I know everything can be changed to my needs, however I want to know what do you in your projects.

How do you organize your routes in Laravel? I like doing Route::resource but I think it mixes API routes and view routes.

I usually do two controllers:

```
TicketsAPIController (json response)

index
store
show
update
destroy

TicketsViewController (view response)

index
create
show
edit
```

What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your routes like this

```
Route::controllers([
 'api' => 'TicketsAPIController ',
 'view' => 'TicketsViewController'
]);
```

Your controller methos

```
/api
public function getIndex()
{  
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think Route::controller has been deprecated https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.3 already achieve this feature, if you read the changelog for laravel 5.3 in laravel website you will note that the `routes.php` no longer exists, instead is located in a folder in the project root called `routes/`, and inside of it you can find two files called `web.php` and `api.php`, if you look deeper you will find that in `RouteServiceProvider.php` every file have it's own uri, by default the routes defined inside of `web.php` will be at the root (/) of the website, and the API routes will be under the `/api` prefix. Bests!

Comment: Yes, I know. But how many controllers do you create? Do you do Route::resource in web.php and also in api.php?

Comment: Well, you can make two different namespaces, or handle the requests by headers and return the response regarding to the type of request you made, let's say `XmlHttpRequest`, for instance, you can put a header `AJAX-REQUEST` and the value `true` in your request if you are achieving this with Javascript, and evaluate this in the action, then you don't even need to define two controllers, just a conditional.